# Не могу разобраться как сделать разные стили двум разным шапкам (Wordpress)

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

У меня есть 2 страницы и на каждой из них есть своя шапка. 2 разные шапки я могу вызвать с помощью `<?php get_header('2'); ?>` и я вызову таким образом **header-2.php**. И внутри этого файла в теге  я вызываю `<?php wp_head(); ?>` . А он загружает стили для **header.php** . Вот что у меня в **function.php**

```
function elkino_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'header', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/header.js', array(), null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'yandex-map-api', 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU', array(), null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'util-calculate-area-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/util.calculateArea.min.js', array(), null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'polylabel-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/polylabel.min.js', array(), null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'newmap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/newmap.js', array(), null, true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'elkino_scripts' );
```

---

Так вот в чем собственно я не могу разобраться. **Как мне сделать так, чтобы в двух разных файлах header.php и header-1.php, загружались разные css и js файлы.**

P.s. я искал в интернете пример, но там показывалось как подключить разные заголовки и все. **Буду очень рад если сможете на примере показать как это должно быть реализовано.**

Comment: Зачем разные css-файлы? ИМХО лучше во втором хедере классы переименовать.и задать их в общем. Или отдельно подключаемом. Дополнительно. а не "вместо". Аналогично и с js.

Comment: Тогда будут загружаться лишние css и js код, что будет замедлять скорость загрузки страницы. Зачем грузить код который не будет использоваться? Оо

Comment: Не экономьте на спичках, так никто не делает. Css в 10 тысяч строк - это ок. @SeVlad правильные вещи говорит

Comment: На а если очень хочется, то надо понимать, что стили грузятся не для header.php, а для сайта в целом. Вам надо в elkino_scripts вставить логику на основе is_page()

Comment: Во первых сss и js кешируется браузером. Во вторых лишний код будет как раз когда будут работать разные файлы.